# What happens when we set interval and set smallest displacement for the LocationRequest in FusedLocationClient?

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm using the  `LocationRequest` for the FusedLocationClient and have setInterval for 30 sec and have setSmallestDisplacement to 10m. Does my code now notify the location in 30 sec or when I've crossed 10 meters?

Answer (score 1):

Displacement is given more weightage than intervals. So, for example, if you have set smallest displacement to 10m and interval to 30 secs, then if there isn't any displacement, no location updates would be received. And if, no displacement is set and interval is set to 30 seconds, then location updates would be received after every 30 seconds.

Comment: setMinUpdateDistanceMeters(15f) and setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(300000) // 300000 is 5 mins. My device is there no table did not move to the distance above 15 meter still i m getting location update after 5mins i expect that i should not get location upload.